# Mysql concatenate parents and children as string

Tags: mysql, database, recursion, hierarchy, recursive-query

This is my database on mysql and I need extract concatenating all the parents and all children.

```
id     | name             | parent_id | has_children
100017 | Roupas Femininas | 0         | 1
100018 | Meias            | 100017    | 1
100419 | Outros           | 100118    | 0
100418 | Meia calça       | 100118    | 0
100417 | Meias            | 100118    | 0
100117 | Tecidos          | 100017    | 1
100416 | Outros           | 100117    | 0
100413 | Lona             | 100117    | 0
100412 | Jeans            | 100117    | 0
```

Example as I need return:

```
Roupas Femininas > Meias > Outros
Roupas Femininas > Meias > Meia calça
Roupas Femininas > Meias > Meias
Roupas Femininas > Tecidos > Outros
Roupas Femininas > Tecidos > Lona
Roupas Femininas > Tecidos > Jeans
```

How can I extract this data from my database to get that example as return?

I've been looking everywhere, and reading this [Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/), but I didn't find the result I was looking for.

I got closer to the expected result, but I couldn't identify the problem.

```
SELECT CONCAT( REPEAT(' > ', COUNT(parent.nome_shopee) - 1), node.nome_shopee) AS name
FROM categoria_shopee_lista AS node,
    categoria_shopee_lista AS parent
WHERE node.categoria_pai BETWEEN parent.categoria_pai AND parent.nome_shopee
GROUP BY node.nome_shopee
ORDER BY node.id;
```

Result:

```
 >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >Roupas Femininas
 >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >  >Outros
 etc...
```

[Mysql online](https://paiza.io/projects/Xj8oTQ5Ap3SzDZscGtkhnA?language=mysql)

Is this the correct way?

thanks

Comment: You don't do that in SQL.  You do that in a program that reads the SQL data and produces the output.

Comment: There are mismatches in your `parent_id` value for the children. Like `Meia calça`, the `parent_id=100118` but in your example output, the `id` for `Meias` is `100018`.

Comment: The idea is that "Meia calça" and "Tecidos" are direct children from "Roupas Femininas", and that them have their children too.

Comment: According to your expected result, `Meia calça` is direct children to `Meias`. If you look at Akina's fiddle, you'll find that the id for `Meias` is `100118` and not `100018` like in your data example. This is probably just a typo from your side but it is crucial that you provide the correct info.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there are max 3 levels (no indefinite depth of levels where recursion should be used) then you do not need chained query just this (just chain your tables three times over next.parent_id=prev.id principle):

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(l1.name,
  IF(l2.name IS NOT NULL,CONCAT(' > ',l2.name,''),
  IF(l3.name IS NOT NULL,CONCAT(' > ',l3.name,''))
FROM categoria_shopee_lista l1
LEFT JOIN categoria_shopee_lista l2 ON l2.parent_id=l1.id
LEFT JOIN categoria_shopee_lista l3 ON l3.parent_id=l2.id
ORDER BY l1.name,l2.name,l3.name
```

Comment: You should test your code in Akina's fiddle.

Comment: Probably I will have cases with more than 3 levels

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS (
  SELECT *, name AS path
  FROM test
  WHERE NOT parent_id
  UNION ALL
  SELECT test.*, CONCAT_WS(' > ', cte.path, test.name)
  FROM cte
  JOIN test ON cte.id = test.parent_id
)
SELECT path
FROM cte
WHERE NOT has_children;
```

| path |
| --- |
| Roupas Femininas > Meias > Outros |
| Roupas Femininas > Meias > Meia calça |
| Roupas Femininas > Meias > Meias |
| Roupas Femininas > Tecidos > Outros |
| Roupas Femininas > Tecidos > Lona |
| Roupas Femininas > Tecidos > Jeans |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eLssaBfX)